# Slicing a String gives no output in python

Tags: python, string, slice

When i run this code it returns nothing

```
name = "Azura"
print(name[-1:-6])
```

Why does this happen ?

Comment: You may find this post very helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're slicing everything in the string from index `-1` to index `-6`. In the case of the string `name`, after converting negative index to positive, that is index `5` to index `0`. In otherwords, when you do `print(name[-1:-6])`, you're doing `print(name[5:0])`, which obviously doesn't work, because python slices left to right. Therefore, if you want `print(name[0:5])`, just do `print(name[-6:-1])`.

TLDR: BAD `print(name[-1:-6])` GOOD `print(name[-6:-1])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a minus index that's going from right to left you must always use a negative step

```
print(name[-1:-6:-1])
```

The direction of the slicing must be the same as the direction of the steps.

Also it's easier to use `string[::-1]` if you want to reverse a string.